# unordered_map is compiling fine but segfaults on execution

Tags: c++, c++11

I am having difficulty in understanding why the below program is giving core dump on execution.

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <unordered_map>
   using namespace std;
   int main()
   {
       std::unordered_map<int,int> hMap;
       return 0;
   }
```

There is no compilation warnings or errors but it gives core dump when I execute it.
 Is this issue related to the platform or compiler? Or am I missing something here?

I am compiling the code using below g++ command

```
g++ -g -Wall -Werror -std=c++11 -o file file.cpp
```

Platform is

```
Linux 3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Sep 25 09:42:57 EDT 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Compiler :

```
gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39) (GCC)
```

On debugging I am getting the following stacktrace:

```
#0  0x0000000000601e30 in memset@@GLIBC_2.2.5 ()
#1  0x0000000000400fd4 in std::_Hashtable<int, std::pair<int const, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, int> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<int>, std::hash<int>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> >::_M_allocate_buckets (
    this=0x7ffffffe8310, __n=11) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/hashtable.h:780
#2  0x0000000000400db4 in std::_Hashtable<int, std::pair<int const, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, int> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<int>, std::hash<int>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> >::_Hashtable (this=0x7ffffffe8310, 
    __bucket_hint=10, __h1=..., __h2=..., __h=..., __eq=..., __exk=..., __a=...) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/hashtable.h:831
#3  0x0000000000400bc5 in std::_Hashtable<int, std::pair<int const, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, int> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<int>, std::hash<int>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> >::_Hashtable (this=0x7ffffffe8310, 
    __n=10, __hf=..., __eql=..., __a=...) at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/hashtable.h:397
#4  0x0000000000400aff in std::unordered_map<int, int, std::hash<int>, std::equal_to<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, int> > >::unordered_map (this=0x7ffffffe8310, __n=10, __hf=..., __eql=..., __a=...)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/unordered_map.h:142
```

Comment: Latest GCC version is 9.2. Can you upgrade?

Comment: You should upgrade your compiler. I did it on my Mac and it seems fine.

Comment: @vll I am not allowed to do compiler upgrade But I need to use unordered_map in my module. Is there any alternative to this?

Comment: Try to compile it with `-std=c++0x`, it might be that in `gcc 4.8.5` `c++11` is not fully supported.

Comment: @dr__noob Do you need to use `unordered_map` because somebody else's interface is using it? Does that code crash too? If not, what did they do differently?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the crash on CentOS7 (`3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64`) with g++ `4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)`. Have you done something funny with your compiler or standard library installation?

Comment: @vll Actually I need it to write some piece of code which has constant lookup time.

Comment: @YSC I am not the owner of the server.I started working on this system recently.

Comment: Can you share what exactly does `g++ -S -g -Wall -Werror -std=c++11 -o file.s file.cpp` outputs (in `file.s`)? Unfortunately, I cannot access pastebin from where I am.

Comment: `std::unordered_set` has the same lookup time as `std::unordered_map`, maybe you can use it?